# How to develop Query Designer in spring based application

Tags: java, sql, spring

I want to generate sql queries at run time, user drag and drop the schema from UI like table name no of fields, joining, conditions. In back end I want to build a sql query by using these input from front end and send the build sql query to front end how to achieve this and which API i need to use.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more concrete about your question?

Comment: You should use criteria for such purpose, if you are not planning to save them to database.

Comment: The obvious choice is JPA Criteria API

Comment: @Thomas Junk I want to build a sql query by using user input.

Comment: @ meskobabazs I am not using hibernate and i don't have entity class.

Answer (score 1):

The most common solution for this is criteriaQuery, but you should seriously consider [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/). It has same functionality as criteria (including dynamic query building), but is more maintainable and readable.